# What would be the purpose of using the reference and dereference operators immediately in sequence "&*B"?

Tags: c++

I have seen this in our code a couple times and it immediately makes me suspicious.  But since I don't know the original intent I am hesitant to remove it.

```
//requires double indirection which I won't go into
FooClass::FooFunction(void ** param)
{
  //do something
}

SomeClass * A = new SomeClass();
SomeClass **B = &A;
FooFunction( reinterpret_cast<void**>(&*B) );   // what is happening here?
```

The "&*B" part is the part in question?  Feel free to integrate explanation of the reinterpret cast but I am pretty familiar with cast techniques.

Comment: Are you sure that "SomeClass ** A = new A();" doesn't contain a type? Shouldn't it be "SomeClass * A = new A();"?

Comment: The code you showed cannot be the one you ask about, because it's wrong (`SomeClass ** A = new A()` won't compile) in a place that's critical for the answer ("what is `A`?"). You will likely need to fix this in order to get meaningful answers.

Comment: This code is ill-formed. You cannot use class name as identifier for variable.

Comment: you are correct.  Adjusted the code according to your finding.  The question is meant for the reference/dereference.

Comment: @BuckFilledPlatypus: It does make some sense now. I have removed my down-vote and made an attempt at answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see only one reason for this: `B` has overloaded `operator*()` to return an `X`, but whoever wrote the code needed an `X*`. (Note that in your code, `X` is `A*`.) The typical case for this is smart pointers and iterators.

If the above isn't the case, maybe the code was written to be generic enough to deal with smart pointers/iterators. Or it used to use smart pointers and whoever changed it didn't bother changing `&*`, too? Have you poked through its history to see when this was introduced and what the code looked then?

Comment: @sbi, so in this case would it be pointless to just use reinterpret_cast<void**>(B) ? I am unaware of an overloaded * operator for this particular ptr, so it seems like we are getting a temporary ptr back for something for which we already have double indirection?

Comment: If `B` is indeed a naked pointer (of type `SomeClass**`) as shown in your question, the it's certainly pointless. (But it doesn't hurt either.)

Comment: Ok, that answers the question then.  If it is not some special case then it is indeed pointless as I am suspecting.

Answer (score 10):

I've done similar things with iterators - dereference the iterator to get a reference, and then do the "&" operator to get a pointer.

I don't see why it would be doing anything here though. If the type to the right of "&*" is a pointer type it does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following sample;

```
class A {
public:
    int f() { return 55; }
};

class B {
public:
    B( A* a ) : a(a) {}
    A*& operator*() { return a; }

    A* a;
};

int main () {
    A* a = new A();
    B b = a;

    // &* calls operator*, then gets address of A
    void** x = reinterpret_cast<void**>(&*b);
    cout << reinterpret_cast<A*>( *x )->f() << endl; // prints 55

    void** x2 = reinterpret_cast<void**>( b );       // compile error
}
```

Your last edit of question leads to:

```
A* a = new A();
A** b = &a;

void** x = reinterpret_cast<void**>(&*b);  // now this is equal to the following
void** x2 = reinterpret_cast<void**>( b ); // so using &* make no sense
```

Comment: If the p isn't a straight pointer, then yes it makes sense (although I'd type &(*p) as p.get()), but it looks like a straight pointer in the question.

Comment: If `A` is a straight pointer here, then OP's question has no sense.

Comment: Kirill, are you saying here that *p gets the pointer to 'b' and then we are creating a new pointer by adding more indirection through the & operator here?  Perhaps I misunderstood with the introduction of shared_ptr.

Comment: Changed sample to remove misunderstanding with `shared_ptr`. That was not really good sample.